# How to go about implementing "Branch Locator" functionality?

Tags: website-features

I'm in a situation where I need to implement a 'branch locator' feature that allows users to enter their postcode (and possibly a radius in which they're willing to travel), for which results will then be returned from my database on a map with driving directions, distances etc.

Does any such product exist? I'm in the UK, so it has to have UK postcode data but I can't find anything and don't really want to have to try and get hacky with the google maps API. I found [Postcode Anywhere](http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk) which would provide me with the distances and postcode data I need, it's just going to be awkward putting it all together.

**EDIT:** I didn't actuall notice that Postcode Anywhere offer a branch locator product. Trouble is, [it's a bit pricey](http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/store-locator-tool/how-much-does-it-cost.aspx?tb). Does anyone know of any better or cheaper solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Prices aren't readily displayed for these, but here are the equivalents from three companies which provide a range of UK postcode related software:

- http://www.qas.co.uk/products/geographic-information-systems/nearest.htm
- http://www.afd.co.uk/product_internet_nearest.asp?ProductID=IN
- http://www.hopewiser.com/products/proximity/